# Custom li list-style with font-awesome icon

Tags: css, html-lists, font-awesome

I am wondering if it's possible to utilize font-awesome (or any other iconic font) classes to create a custom `<li>` list-style-type?

I am currently using jQuery to do this, ie:

```
$("li.myClass").prepend("<i class=\"icon-chevron-right\"></i>");
```

However, this doesn't style properly when the `<li>` text wraps across the page as it considers the icon to be part of the text, not the actual bullet-indicator.

Any tips?

Comment: **IMPORTANT NOTICE**: Several answers below state that the `::marker` psudeo-element is not supported. It is now supported across [several browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Amarker)

Answer (score 388, accepted):

[CSS Lists and Counters Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudoelement) introduces the `::marker` pseudo-element. From what I've understood it would allow such a thing. <strike>Unfortunately, no browser seems to support it</strike>.

The following solution works with any type of icon font. But FontAwesome apparently provides its own way to accomplish this (I was unaware of it before writing my answer). Check out Darrrrrren's answer below for more details.

It works by adding some padding to the parent `ul` and pulling the icon into that padding:

```css
ul {
  --icon-space: 1.3em;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: var(--icon-space);
}

li:before {
  content: "\f00c"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: calc( var(--icon-space) * -1 );
  width: var(--icon-space);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
</ul>
```

Adjust the padding/font-size/etc to your liking, and that's it.

=====

**Edit:**

As of now the `::marker` pseudo-element already has 90% support across browsers. Below is an implementation making using of it.

```
ul {
  --icon-size: .8em;
  --gutter: .5em;
  padding: 0 0 0 var(--icon-size);
}

ul li {
  padding-left: var(--gutter);
}

ul li::marker {
  content: "\f00a"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: var(--icon-size);
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks.  I'll try this tonight when I get a chance and will likely accept your answer then (or have further questions).

Comment: ;) no problem. Glad to have helped.

Comment: Just wanted to note - that I did need to include `font-family: FontAwesome;` to the `li:before` - I'm sure that's obvious to you but wanted to include it for completeness in case anyone reads this for their own problem.

Comment: I have made a reference page of the CSS content codes corresponding to each Font Awesome icon here: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Comment: Any idea how to use this within SASS? `content: "&#xf0f6;";` produces the text representation, not the icon. `content: &#xf0f6;` throws an error...

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem - http://jsfiddle.net/rXQsy/ . Are you sure you've included the font's css?

Comment: This solution even works with multi column elements. (Others that use position:absolute don't)

Comment: @Astrotim You can get these codes directly from the official FontAwesome cheatsheet: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: Or use http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ search and click the icon you want.

Comment: This solution needs slight revisions for use with FontAwesome 5.  You need font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'; as well as an explicit font-weight for it to work.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894414/the-before-pseudo-element-not-working-in-font-awesome-v-5

Comment: I need to add a specific weight to get this to work: `font-weight: 900;`

Comment: Your CSS code for spacing is not ideal I would recommend simply adding a `margin-right: .3rem;` to the `:before` and that's it.

Comment: There's actually a reason I did it this way and not like that: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/Ltnf01v2/2/

Answer (score 80):

As per the [Font Awesome Documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list):

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>Barbabella</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>Barbaletta</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>Barbalala</li>
</ul>
```

Or, using Jade:

```
ul.fa-ul
  li
    i.fa-li.fa.fa-check
    | Barbabella
  li
    i.fa-li.fa.fa-check
    | Barbaletta
  li
    i.fa-li.fa.fa-check
    | Barbalala
```

Comment: This worked in vue for me like this `<ul class="fa-ul"><li class="h4"><font-awesome-icon icon="check" /> ...`

Answer (score 53):

I'd like to provide an alternate, easier solution that is specific to FontAwesome.  If you're using a different iconic font, JOPLOmacedo's answer is still perfectly fine for use.

[FontAwesome now handles list styles internally with CSS classes](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list).

Here's the official example:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: With last Font-Awesome you must replace "icons-ul" by "fa-ul" and "icon-li" by "fa-li" :  [code] <ul class="fa-ul"> <li class="fa-li fa fa-check"> ...</li></ul>[/code]

Answer (score 6):

I did two things inspired by @OscarJovanny comment, with some hacks.

Step 1:

- Download icons file as svg from [Here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/check-circle?style=solid), as I only need only this icon from font awesome

Step 2:

```css
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

ul li {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

ul li::before {
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 1px;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -1.3em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-mask-image: url("./assets/img/check-circle-solid.svg");
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can i use `png` instead of `svg`? thank you

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add to JOPLOmacedo's answer. His solution is my favourite, but I always had problem with indentation when the li had more than one line. It was fiddly to find the correct indentation with margins etc. But this might concern only me.

For me absolute positioning of the `:before` pseudo-element works best. I set `padding-left` on ul, negative position left on the `:before` element, same as ul's `padding-left`. To get the distance of the content from the `:before` element right I just set the `padding-left` on the li. Of course the li has to have position relative. For example

```
ul {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  /* make space for li's :before */
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.4em;
  /* text distance to icon */
}

li:before {
  font-family: 'my-icon-font';
  content: 'character-code-here';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  /* same as ul padding-left */
  top: 0.65em;
  /* depends on character, maybe use padding-top instead */
  /*  .... more styling, maybe set width etc ... */
}
```

Hopefully this is clear and has some value for someone else than me.

Comment: To all the beginners, this is formatted in a CSS preprocessing language called SASS. Pure CSS cannot be nested in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  background-image: url("./assets/img/control.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}
```

Or you can try this if you want to change the color:

```
li::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-right: 7px;

  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("./assets/img/control.svg");
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that the `::marker` element is available in [evergreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evergreen_(software)) [browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Amarker), this is how you could use it, including using `:hover` to change the marker. As you can see, now you can use any Unicode character you want as a list item marker and even use custom counters.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@counter-style fancy {
  system: fixed;
  symbols:   ;
  suffix: " ";
}

p {
  margin-left: 8em;
}

p.note {
  display: list-item;
  counter-increment: note-counter;
}

p.note::marker {
  content: "Note " counter(note-counter) ":";
}

ol {
  margin-left: 8em;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ol li {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

ol li::marker {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 8em;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul.happy li::marker {
  content: "";
}

ul.happy li:hover {
  color: blue;
}

ul.happy li:hover::marker {
  content: "";
}

ul.fancy {
  list-style: fancy;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the first paragraph in this document.</p>
<p class="note">This is a very short document.</p>
<ol>
  <li>This is the first item.
    <li>This is the second item.
      <li>This is the third item.
</ol>
<p>This is the end.</p>

<ul class="happy">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="fancy">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version: [FontAwesome 5 ul](https://jsfiddle.net/fredericklim/23vLynao/2/)

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
ul li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 4px); /* half font-size */
  left: 0px;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f111";
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Line 1</li>
  <li>Line 2</li>
  <li>Line 3</li>
  <li>Line 4</li>
  <li>Line 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

See reference : https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to describe your answer a bit more, instead of just pasting the solution. Grab highlights and find the specific part of documentation instead of just pasting a link to documentation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29958191)