# Can you style ordered list numbers?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, sprite

I'm trying to style the numbers in a ordered list, I'd like to add background-color, border-radius and color so they match the design I'm working from:

[image]

I guess it's not possible and I'll have to use different images for each number i.e.

```
ol li:first-child {list-style-image:url('1.png')};
ol li:nth-child(2) {list-style-image:url('2.png');} 
etc...
```

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You can research for a solution from my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/Hj8Nn/ BTW, I don't think this is **impossible** to search, searching first may give you **a lot of results**, right in SO, this kind of question has been asked many times.

Comment: some links for the info
1. http://codeitdown.com/ordered-list-css-styles/
2. http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/
Its a good qtn, but little bit of searching might have got you the answer

Comment: @KingKing - I'd suggest marking this as a duplicate then...

Answer (score 253, accepted):

You can do this using  [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters), in conjunction with the `:before` pseudo element:

```css
 ol {
   list-style: none;
   counter-reset: item;
 }
 li {
   counter-increment: item;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 li:before {
   margin-right: 10px;
   content: counter(item);
   background: lightblue;
   border-radius: 100%;
   color: white;
   width: 1.2em;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The `counter-reset: item;` should go in the ol block, otherwise the counter will not be reset in nested <ol>.

Comment: a nice solution, but how is the rendering when the body of the `li` element is more than one line?

Comment: I think that, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354578/custom-li-list-style-with-font-awesome-icon, you can use for example ` margin-left: -2.0em;
 width: -2.0em;`

Comment: A value of `50%` for `border-radius` (rather than `100%`) is sufficient to get a circle. (See, e.g., Lea Verou, "[The curious case of border-radius:50%](http://lea.verou.me/2010/10/the-curious-case-of-border-radius50/)," October 30, 2010.)

Comment: @cmhughes - if you wanted to do that, you'd give the `li` `position: relative;`, and then for `:before` you'd give that `position: absolute;` and then use `top` and `left` to position it exactly as you like.

Comment: How do you stop this applying to nested <ol><li> that have a,b,c etc

Comment: the "start" attribute for ol does not work with this solution.

Answer (score 27):

I was looking for something different, and found this example at CodePen;

try this: http://codepen.io/sawmac/pen/txBhK

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
}
.custom-counter {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-counter li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.custom-counter li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 11px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li>This is the first item</li>
  <li>This is the second item</li>
  <li>This is the third item</li>
  <li>This is the fourth item</li>
  <li>This is the fifth item</li>
  <li>This is the sixth item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 18):

**2021 update**, you can use the `::marker` pseudo element selector in recent browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

```css
 li::marker {
   color: red;
 }
 li {
   color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: cool! does this work on Chrome and Safari?

Comment: @Pixelomo yes but with some restrictions on what can and can't be styled. For simple stuff like color it works nicely. https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo

Comment: Judging by CanIUse, as of 2022 there don't seem to be any more restrictions on usage and all modern browsers seem to support it well.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
}
.custom-counter {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-counter li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.custom-counter li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 11px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li>This is the first item</li>
  <li>This is the second item</li>
  <li>This is the third item</li>
  <li>This is the fourth item</li>
  <li>This is the fifth item</li>
  <li>This is the sixth item</li>
</ol>
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
}
.custom-counter {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-counter li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.custom-counter li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 11px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li>This is the first item</li>
  <li>This is the second item</li>
  <li>This is the third item</li>
  <li>This is the fourth item</li>
  <li>This is the fifth item</li>
  <li>This is the sixth item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is:

```
    ol li::marker {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Works in Chrome.