# How to underline an ordered list's bullet?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code but the "2." is not being underlined. Any help is appreciated.

```
<li> <span style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">ComicCon 1990 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp; </span> </li>
```

Comment: I cannot see a "2." on your code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you style ordered list numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610151/can-you-style-ordered-list-numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use your own counter, but it is possible.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

ul li {
  text-decoration: underline;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

If you want just the numbers underlined, move that attribute to the ::before property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the alternative to your approach, you can use the numbers instead of bullets for example, you can put the numbers inside the `li` tags so they will be treated as inside content. Then you can provide appropriate padding or margin to style them, for example your above code will become,

```
<li> <span style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">2. ComicCon 1990 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp; </span> </li>
```

Note that I have just added `2.` before `ComicCon 1990` in your code, to insert make the bullet effect explicitly. Make sure that you have to hide the list bullets,which you can do so as,

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Note : If you don't want to add numbers to the `li` elements manually, then you can write a little Javascript code to do that for you. I hope that will help you.

Comment: You can also use the counter as shown in the answer given below by David

Answer (score 0):

This method is also useful

```
 <head>
    <style type="text/css">
         li.underline { 
                        text-decoration: underline;
             }

            li.underline:before {
                        content: "\2022";
                }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<ol>
    <li><span class= "underline"> ABC</span></li>

</ol></body>
```