# How to underline all the text in a ordered list when hovering over an item

Tags: css, sass, hover

I'm using scss and I need to undeline all the text (number and text) when hovering over the `li` item

this is an example but the number still not underlined

https://jsfiddle.net/viking_123/9hgjyo05/1/

```
<ol>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
</ol>
```

SCSS

```
 ol li {
   cursor:pointer;
   &:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
   }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586267/how-to-underline-an-ordered-lists-bullet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `list-style-position: inside;` on the `<ol>` element. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

```css
 ol {
   /* Add this to style*/
   list-style-position: inside;

   li {
     cursor:pointer;

     &:hover {
       text-decoration: underline;
     }
   }

 }
```

[image]

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blackraspberryyyy/87r6f03a/15/).

**NOTE:** Thanks to @Rayees AC for catching this. This approach behaves differently on Mozilla Firefox browsers because for some reason, `text-decoration` does not apply on `::markers` (aka the list bullets). If you need to support other browsers, try [@Rayees AC's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63722398/9183405) instead.

Comment: This `list-style-position: inside;` to <ol> element ? right?

Comment: No, it should be in <li> element.

Comment: isn't working properly? can you add a demo in **jsfiddle** or **codepen**

Comment: @RayeesAC, sorry I stand corrected. It should also work on <ol> element too. Here's a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/blackraspberryyyy/87r6f03a/10/

Comment: Ok, but the number not included in underline. read question ' underline all the text (number and text) when hovering over the li item '. he want the underline including the number and text also.

Comment: Yup, the number and text is both underlined on hover. Have you checked my fiddle? I'll also attach an image so you can see the output.

Comment: not working in firefox browser. can you check man..

Comment: You're right. For some reason, `text-decoration` does not apply on `::markers` (the list bullets) on Mozilla Firefox browsers. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this instead,

[**`jsfiddle Demo`**](https://jsfiddle.net/Rayeesac/x9cqhof7/)

Please add `list-style-position:inside;` and `display:inline-block;` to `<ol>`.

Also add **border-bottom** to `<li>`

**SCSS**

```
ol{
   list-style-position:inside;
   display:inline-block;
 }
ol li {
   cursor:pointer;
   border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
   &:hover {
     border-bottom:2px solid #111;
   }
 }
```

**Working Demo**

```css
ol{
   list-style-position:inside;
   display:inline-block;
}

ol li {
   cursor:pointer;
   border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
   float: left;
   clear: left;
}

ol li:hover {
   border-bottom:2px solid #111;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Can you check this @Victor ?  if any doubt comment here.