# how to implement list bullets in CSS

Tags: css

I have the following bullets for list items. How can I implement these bullets in CSS?

See image

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you style ordered list numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610151/can-you-style-ordered-list-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610151/can-you-style-ordered-list-numbers) answer, I edited it so it's what you wanted

CSS

```
body {
   counter-reset: item;
 }
 ol {
   list-style: none;
 }
 li {
   counter-increment: item;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 li:before {
   margin-right: 10px;
   content: counter(item);
   border-radius: 100%;
   border:2px solid #29465F;
   color:#29465F;
   font-weight:700;
   width: 1.2em;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

HTML

```
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/gptd7nyd/) a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/k36qjnq4/ Here is a working fiddle.

and the css styles are

```
 ol {
   list-style: none;
 }
 li {
    counter-increment: item;  
    margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 li:before {
   margin-right: 5px;  
   content: counter(item);
   border-radius: 100%;
   border:1px solid; 
   width: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a circle with a number in it using assuming you are in a loop and have access to the index of the array:

```
<li>
    <span class="list-item-number">{{i+1}}</span>
    <span class="lite-item-value">{{item.name}}</li>
</li>

.list-item-number {
    border-radius: 100rem;
    width: 1rem;
    border: .2rem solid blue;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is that an angularJS syntax?

Comment: Yes, but angular syntax is pretty common for most client side templating these days. What are you using?

Comment: @chovy th OP has only CSS tag. So you cant be sure that he uses angular. I agree its common now a days but still

Comment: It's just that this question is about CSS and not AngularJS