# Style subitems in ordered list numbers with CSS

Tags: css, list, css-counter

I will use an other design for an ordered list. So I found a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610151/can-you-style-ordered-list-numbers) here on SO.

```css
body { counter-reset: item; }

ol.numbered_style li:before
{
    counter-increment:item;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    content:counter(item);
    background:gold;
    border-radius:100%;
    color:white;
    width:1.2em;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}

ol.none, ul.none,ol.numbered_style { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<ol class="numbered_style">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third
        <ol class="none">
            <li>Subitem</li> 
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Fourth
        <ul class="none">
            <li>Other Subitem</li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

How is it possible not to use this style for sub-items in a list?
Why isn't the conditions for my class called `none` not working?
Also what do I have to do, if I want a second ordered list with the same class. It should ***begin with 1***. `<ol class="numbered_style" start="1">` didn't helped.
Is it possible to start a ordered list with a specify number like 2 or 1.1? For a normal `ol` I could use `start="number"`, but I think it is disabled because of `ol.numbered_style { list-style: none; }`.

Comment: Use child selector `ol.numbered_style> li:before` instead of descendant selector. `list-style-type` has no effect because the numbering is generated using counters.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't need this now, but is there also a solution to start this ordered list with a specify number like 2 or 1.1?

Comment: Both are possible but the latter takes more coding. Please refer to the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as an answer since there are more than one part to the question:

> 1. How is it possible not to use this style for subitems in a list?

Use the children selector (`>`) to select only the `li` that are directly present under the parent `ol` tag instead of selecting all `li` elements that are at any level under the parent `ol` tag. The `list-style` setting has no effect here because the numbering here is generated and added using counters.

> 2. But what do I have to do, if I want a second ordered list with the same class. It should began with 1.

Add a `counter-reset` with the `ol.numbered_style` selector so that the number is reset everytime that element is encountered. This will make it restart at 1.

> 3. I don't need this now, but is there also a solution to start this ordered list with a specify number like 2 or 1.1?

Yes, starting it at `2` is possible. In the `counter-reset` property we can also provide the initial value of the counter (as the second in a list of space separated values). Refer below snippet for a demo.

```css
body, ol.numbered_style {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol.numbered_style.starts_at_2 {
  counter-reset: item 1; /* the second is the start value, default is 0 */
}
ol.numbered_style > li:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: counter(item);
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
ol.none, ul.none, ol.numbered_style {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="numbered_style">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third
    <ol class="none">
      <li>Subitem</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Fourth
    <ul class="none">
      <li>Other Subitem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>

<ol class="numbered_style">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third
    <ol class="none">
      <li>Subitem</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Fourth
    <ul class="none">
      <li>Other Subitem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>

<ol class="numbered_style starts_at_2">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third
    <ol class="none">
      <li>Subitem</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Fourth
    <ul class="none">
      <li>Other Subitem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Making it start at `1.1` is a bit more tricky as we have to add one counter at `ol` level and another at `li` level. Below is a sample demo.

```css
body{
  counter-reset: ol ;
}
ol.numbered_style{
  counter-reset: li;
  counter-increment: ol;
}
ol.numbered_style > li:before {
  counter-increment: li;
  content: counter(ol) "." counter(li);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
ol.none, ul.none, ol.numbered_style {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="numbered_style">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third
    <ol class="none">
      <li>Subitem</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Fourth
    <ul class="none">
      <li>Other Subitem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. A have a new case: I want to add a letter in the "yellow box" to only to one `<li>` element. I tried `li::before { content: " a ";}`

Comment: @Grischa: I think you should create another new question because that is a new case.