# A styled ordered list whose nested list should have numbers with letters using CSS counter property

Tags: css, list, css-counter

I want to add a letter to an `<li>`-element from a my under `<ol>` like from [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36099931/3751899):

```css
body { counter-reset: item; }

ol.numbered_style li:before
{
    counter-increment:item;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    content:counter(item);
    background:blue;
    border-radius:100%;
    color:white;
    width:1.2em;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
ol.numbered_style.start_3{
  counter-reset: item 2; 
}

ol.none, ul.none,ol.numbered_style { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<ol class="numbered_style">
 <li>first</li>
 <li>second</li>
 <li>third  Lorem Ipsum
  <ol class="numbered_style start_3">
   <li>missing an a after the number</li>
   <li>missing a b after the number</li>
   <li>missing a c after the number</li>
  </ol>
 </li>
</ol>
```

I have tried `li::before { content: " a ";}`, but this didn't work. I also want  a solution, in which adding in a second counter can generate the next elements with the following alphanumeric pattern like `list-style-type: lower-alpha;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do anything that the `<ol>` can do.

```
ol.numbered_style.start_3{
  counter-reset: item2; 
}

ol.numbered_style.start_3 li:before {
    counter-increment:item2;
    content:counter(item2, upper-latin);
}/* List Style Type========^----------^*/
```

**Counter List Style Types**

> - decimal ------------------------------- 1, 2, 3, ...
> - decimal-leading-zero -------------- 01, 02, 03, ... 09, 10, 11, ...
> - lower-alpha,
>     lower-latin    ----------- a, b, c, ... z, aa, ab, ...
> - upper-alpha,
>     upper-latin    ---------- A, B, C, ... Z, AA, AB, ...
> - lower-roman ------------------------ i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, ...
> - upper-roman ------------------------ I, II, III, IV, V, VI, ...
> - asterisks ----------------------------- `*, **, ***,`...

**REFERENCE**

http://www.princexml.com/doc/5.1/counters/

**SNIPPET**

```css
body { counter-reset: item; }

ol.numbered_style li:before
{
    counter-increment:item;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    content:counter(item, upper-roman);
    background:blue;
    border-radius:100%;
    color:white;
    width:1.2em;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
ol.numbered_style.start_3{
  counter-reset: item2; 
}

ol.numbered_style.start_3 li:before {

    counter-increment:item2;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    content:"3"counter(item2, upper-latin);
    background:blue;
    border-radius:100%;
    color:white;
    width:1.2em;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
  
ol.none, ul.none,ol.numbered_style { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<ol class="numbered_style">
 <li>first</li>
 <li>second</li>
 <li>third  Lorem Ipsum
  <ol class="numbered_style start_3">
   <li>missing an a after the number</li>
   <li>missing an b after the number</li>
   <li>missing an c after the number</li>
  </ol>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want 3a, 3b, 3c not only a,b,c

Comment: @Grischa See Updated demo `content:"3"counter(item2, upper-latin);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```css
ol.main {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol.main li {
  counter-increment: item;
}
ol.numbered_style li:before {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: counter(item);
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
ol.numbered_style ol.numbered_style li {
  counter-increment: subitem;
}
ol.numbered_style ol.numbered_style li:before {
  content: counter(item) counter(subitem, lower-alpha);
}
ol.none,
ul.none,
ol.numbered_style {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="main numbered_style">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third Lorem Ipsum
    <ol class="numbered_style">
      <li>missing an a after the number</li>
      <li>missing a b after the number</li>
      <li>missing a c after the number</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<hr>

<ol class="main numbered_style">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third Lorem Ipsum
    <ol class="numbered_style">
      <li>missing an a after the number</li>
      <li>missing a b after the number</li>
      <li>missing a c after the number</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```