# CSS nested ordered list numbered with alphanumerical characters

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an ordered list where numbering style is alphanumerical characters in nested lists too.

Example:

```
a. one
b. two
   b.a. three
   b.b. four
   b.c. five
c. six
   c.a. seven
      c.a.a. eight
   c.b. nine
      c.b.a. ten
d. eleven
```

I have tried setting list-style-type to lower-alpha but it doesn't number nested lists correctly.
I have achived what I want with numbers like this:

```
 ol {
    counter-reset: section;  
    list-style-type: none;
 }
 li {
    counter-increment: section;
 }
 li::before {  
    content: counters(section,".") ". ";
}
```

Now I want the same thing but with alphanumerical characters as numbering style.
The solution can be done in HTML, CSS or JS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859932/style-an-ordered-list-like-1-1-1-2-instead-of-1-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A styled ordered list whose nested list should have numbers with letters using CSS counter property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682602/a-styled-ordered-list-whose-nested-list-should-have-numbers-with-letters-using-c). [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e4og9rfs/) based on  [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36683273/924299).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use type -'a' for orderlist

```html
<ol type="a">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
  <ol type="a">
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ol></li>
</ol>
```

Refer this link for different ordered types - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

**type**
Indicates the numbering type:
'a' indicates lowercase letters,
'A' indicates uppercase letters,
'i' indicates lowercase Roman numerals,
'I' indicates uppercase Roman numerals,
and '1' indicates numbers (default).

Code sample to achieve expected format

```css
ol{
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol > li:before{
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha)".";
}

ol li ol{
    counter-reset: letter;
}
ol ol li:before{
    counter-increment: letter;
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha)"."counter(letter, lower-alpha) " ";
}
```

```html
<ol type="a"> 
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
  <ol>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ol></li>
</ol>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rgPgBO

**Explanation:**

1. Reset list style for all ordered list and reset counter to initial default
2. Add **content - counter(item, lower-alpha)"."** with list type lower-alpha for list and sublist
3. Reset counter for sublist to start from initial default value (in this case - 'a')
4. Use **content: counter(item, lower-alpha)"."counter(letter, lower-alpha) " "**  to use existing order value from list followed by sublist counter

Comment: Please see example I posted in my question.