# finding out the correct css path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using a plugin call fullPage.js and I am wondering if I could use jquery to change the bullets of navigation on the right.

So this is the HTML code of the navigation bar

```
<div id="fp-nav" class="right" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin-top: -63.5px;">
  <ul>
    <li data-tooltip="">
      <a href="#home" class="">
      <span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

I am trying out and wondering how do I reach  because this is the place to change the bullet to something I want to.

I want to use ionicons.css icons.

So for example, I tried doing this.

```
$("#fp-nav#home span").addClass("icon ion-home");
```

This piece of code is not working and I am wondering did I get the path correctly?

Comment: You could use pure css: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13354689/3269816

Comment: You haven't shown us the path or your folder structure...so we have no way of knowing.

Comment: i guess he is talking about the selector path not folder structure @Paulie_D

Comment: The actual answer to the question is: `#fp-nav #home span`.

Comment: Ah I see ...@AndreasFurster has it.

Comment: But i don't think it will solve his problem

Comment: I just try adding #fp-nav #home span {
 content: "\f1c9";
    font-family: ionicons;
} to my css and it didnt change the icon..

Comment: the content property can be only used in `:before` or `:after`

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you could use pure css like this:

```html
    <html>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    ul li:before{
      font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    }
    ul.myList li:before {
    content: "\f015";
    }
    ul.myOtherList li:before {
    content: "\f04e";
    }
    </style>
       <body>
          <ul class="myList">
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>baz</li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="myOtherList">
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>baz</li>
          </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And instead if `'>> '` you could use the char and font from your icons.

Comment: Because every content is different, so how do I know which li:before belongs to which?

Comment: You could give the ul a class or id.

Comment: I think I found my own solution. I do not know if I can do this or not but I did change everything accordingly

Comment: Than post your own answer. Maybe we can learn from each other ;)

Answer (score 1):

These information can help you:

```
ul {
 list-style-type: square;
 list-style-position: outside;
 list-style-image: none;
}
```

and These are the values for "list-style-type" property :

```
disc
circle
square
decimal
decimal-leading-zero
lower-roman
upper-roman
lower-greek
lower-latin
upper-latin
armenian
georgian
lower-alpha
upper-alpha
none
```

and if you want your icon , you can use list-style-image property.

Comment: No, he want's his own icon, not one of your list

Comment: He can do that by the list-style-image property.

Comment: Isn't the format of the icon a png,gif,ico file? :)

Comment: Aha. list-style-image get the image as the icon of your list!

Comment: The most iconsheets are based on fonts. The font-sheet is actually a font-family. Take a look at font-awesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: It's one way. We can use images too, you know ...
but thanks because of the link. I haven't seen it till now :)

Answer (score 0):

I went into jquery.fullPage.js

Somewhere there is this create vertical navigation bar section

All I did was, according to my link anchor names, I create seperate codes to make different icons..

Here it is..

```
        if(link == 'home') {
        nav.find('ul').append('<li data-tooltip="' + tooltip + '"><a href="#' + link + '"><span class="icon ion-home"></span></a></li>');
        } else if(link == 'about') {
            nav.find('ul').append('<li data-tooltip="' + tooltip + '"><a href="#' + link + '"><span class="icon ion-person"></span></a></li>'); 
        } else if(link == 'serv'){
            nav.find('ul').append('<li data-tooltip="' + tooltip + '"><a href="#' + link + '"><span class="icon ion-gear-b"></span></a></li>');
        } else if(link == 'team'){
            nav.find('ul').append('<li data-tooltip="' + tooltip + '"><a href="#' + link + '"><span class="icon ion-ios7-people"></span></a></li>');
        } else if(link == 'portfolio'){
            nav.find('ul').append('<li data-tooltip="' + tooltip + '"><a href="#' + link + '"><span class="icon ion-images"></span></a></li>');
        } else if(link == 'contact'){
            nav.find('ul').append('<li data-tooltip="' + tooltip + '"><a href="#' + link + '"><span class="icon ion-email"></span></a></li>');
        } else {
            nav.find('ul').append('<li data-tooltip="' + tooltip + '"><a href="#' + link + '"><span></span></a></li>');
        }
```

Comment: This is a perfect example where it's a lot nicer to use a `switch` statement. I didn't know you had that much variations.