# How to change the style of li element decoration from bullet point to an chevron

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

I am currently creating a list this should instead of the default element `●` would like to have a `chevron right` like in the example photo. However, I do not use bootstrap but Bulma. Is there an option to get this somehow without bootstrap. I did it with the character `>`. However, this one is not as nice as the [chevron right](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/chevron-right/) .

So my question how can I replace the character '`>`' with such a '`chevron right`' without using bootstrap?

[chevron right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGiCP.png)

HTML

```
<ul className="footer-link">
    <li>
        First 1
    </li>
    <li>
        Second 1
    </li>
    <li>
        Third 1
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```css
.footer-link ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.footer-link ul li {
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}

.footer-link li:before {
    content: ">";
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

What I want

The chevron in this example is isosceles and moreover it is centered from the text height.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGf0y.png)

```
<i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the `::marker` pseudo element? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

It seems to be relatively new, so keep browser support in mind: https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo

An example:

```css
ul li::marker {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f054";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
</ul>


<!-- This is just needed to that I can use FontAwesome here on SO -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work with `:marker` but with the `:before` it did work

Comment: I have tested my code in Firefox + Chrome and it worked in both. Are you maybe using an older browser that is not supported according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo)? Using `::before` also works, that is true. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354578/custom-li-list-style-with-font-awesome-icon

Answer (score 0):

are you allowed to use font awesome?

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.0/js/all.js"></script>

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>First 1</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>Second 1</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>Third 1</li>
</ul>
```